# Python RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long scalars

Tags: python, runtime

Доброго времени суток всем.

Поскольку код слишком большой, прилагаю ссылку на repl:
https://replit.com/@PabloJunior1/Explicit-scheme

Пытаюсь реализовать явную разностную схему для одного двумерного уравнения. Все формулы выразил точно, и программа вполне работает и сходится после 256 итераций, если использую шаг по времени τ=0.25*h^2. Но если использую шаг τ=h^2, то примерно после 370-ой итерации вылезает эта ошибка и процесс уходит в вечный цикл. К сожалению, необходимо использовать именно такое значение. Уже и пытался назначать всем массивам тип float64, всё равно не вышло. Как исправить, вообще не знаю.

Отмечу, что при нынешних параметрах N1=N2=10 и погрешности eps=10^(-5), при шаге τ=h^2 программа должна сойтись ориентировочно за 75-85 шагов. Проверил с помощью неявной схемы и схемы переменных направлений. Также при необходимости могу приложить исходные формулы.